# files send through bluetooth or wifi in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, wifi

> i want to develop an application. i.e. chating without internet .
>   here my goals  are . I Researched Lot of things. i don't know my idea is working or not  . can anyone Suggest me where can i Start.

- from iphone to any other devices to it communicate.
- it can receive messages from other Apple devices .
- i want to develop an application like chating application .
- with this application i will able to chat without internet.
- from where can i start how to proceed give suggestions

**EDIT :1**

For the reference i found a app named [FireChat](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id719829352?mt=8)  . from this app reference i want to enhance . how they implement i don't know . i haven't find any sources .

Answer (score 2):

You can share file only between ios devices(iphone,ipad,ipod) but not other devices.No, You have no permission. But you can send file between cross platform (iphone <-> android) by wifi. NSNetService is the native API by which you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Using BLE or WiFi seems to be the only real choice, Unfortunately both of them have a limited range of around 50m straight line on obstacles. 
Or you could make a hardware solutions like using Xbee which have a maximum range of 14 km